# Which mode should I select for my router?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

In my router's admin panel I see three options for connection speed:

1. Up to  54 Mbps
2. Up to  65 Mbps
3. Up to  150 Mbps

Which option should I choose. What's the benefit (if any) of choosing a slower speed?

Comment: Read about the different a/b/g/n/... standards [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Protocols) (speeds, interference with neighbouring networks and so on).

Comment: What router is this?

Comment: Netgear JNR1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess:

**Up to 54Mb/sec**:
This is the speed mostly used for wireless B and G networks.
**If you have devices which only have Wireless B and G (and not N) then select this.**
If you have two routers and want one to do wireless-N and one wireless-G,L then also select this. (and select wireless N on the other router)

**Up to 65 Mbps**
Never had or 65. Some sort of custom thing?
Update from a comment: 2.4GHz wide band.

**Up to 150 Mbps**
That seems to be 1 way wireless N in the 5GHz band.  That band is preferred since it is both faster and there are more bands at 5Ghz, which avoids problems with other access points. (Read: If you and your neighbours all use the 2.4GHz band for G or B then you are jamming each other.)

Comment: 65 Mbps is what you get with a 20 MHz channel for MCS 7.